# Вывод ::placeholder поверх input средствами css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите, как сделать `placeholder` над рамкой `input`? `z-index` не работает. Оставил его в коде на всякий случай. Есть вариант использовать `span` или `label` с абсолютным позиционированием но `label` уже занят, а лишние элементы не хотелось бы вводить без необходимости. Хочется сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

input::placeholder {
  transition-duration: .3s;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  z-index: 100;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateY(-18px);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="female">Фамилия:</label><br>
  <input id="female" placeholder="Фамилия *" required>
  <label for="name">Имя:</label><br>
  <input id="name" placeholder="Имя *" required>
  <label for="surname">Отчество:</label><br>
  <input id="surname" placeholder="Отчество">
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/Merlin1618/pen/jKVBLL

Есть вариант подключить jQuery библиотеку (jQuery-Floating-Placeholder), но хотелось бы обойтись своими силами.

Comment: Оберните ваши `input` каким-либо `div` и добавляйте элементы с `position: absolute`. Псевдоэлементы для `input` работают только в Chrome. И вам к тому же надо во все `input` добавить крестики, поэтому без этого не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgb(60, 239, 90);
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

.form label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 15px;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 0 5px;
  transition: top .5s;
  }

.form input:focus ~ label {
  top: -10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input id="female" required>
  <label for="female">Фамилия:</label><br>
</form>
```

Такое нужно было?

Answer (score -2):

Каждый элемент может находиться как ниже, так и выше других объектов веб-страницы, их размещением по z-оси и управляет z-index. Это свойство работает только для элементов, у которых значение position задано как absolute, fixed или relative. [Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index)

Comment: ::placeholder не является элементом страницы, чтобы им так манипулировать